# Manipulate the dot command without editing text in insert mode

Tags: vimscript, register

I need to manipulate the dot command without directly editing the buffer for a plugin I'm developing.

The plugin needs to manually append text to the dot command that will be executed while in insert mode.

I would like to have as little side effects as possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because, as you say, it is read-only (`:h registers` confirms this).  Can you achieve your plugin's aim a different way?

Comment: would really like to hear what the use-case is here, as the dot register is quite rarely used, and very different from other registers

Comment: @mass I have a plugin (https://github.com/tversteeg/registers.nvim) that will open a popup with all registers which you can then choose to paste when pressing <C-R> in insert mode. The problem is that during the opening of the window the mode is changed, so the dot command doesn't function properly after that: https://github.com/tversteeg/registers.nvim/issues/19

Comment: @tversteeg what about using `<cmd>` to not change the mode?

Comment: @tversteeg I would also just removed dot register from your list. And suggest users to use `<C-a>` instead or `<C-r>.`

Comment: @MaximKim I'm already using `<cmd>`: `inoremap <silent> <C-R> <C-O><cmd>Registers i<CR>
`. And the problem is not the dot register in the list, but using it after the window is closed.

Comment: `C-O` shouldn't be there then. Cause `<cmd>` was introduced exactly for this.

Comment: BTW, the issue you have linked is about dot command (repeat last change) and not a dot register that contains last inserted text.

Comment: @MaximKim I was confused about the functionality, I've edited the post.

Comment: Oh, jeez. That's a totally different animal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, the problem is that your plugin will do an operation which leaves the "dot" repeat command in an inconsistent state.  From the question, I don't know what this operation is, but generally you can re-structure your plugin in a way that it will work as expected.

You can use the `g@` operator feature to run arbitrary commands which are repeatable.  The following is an example using `wincmd`, however you can replace this with another command or function call.

This is a completely native method which should be preferred to e.g., vim-repeat which require re-mapping the dot command.

```
function! RepWincmd(...)
    execute (v:count ? v:count : s:rep[1]) 'wincmd' s:rep[0]
endfunction

function! s:setup(rep, ...)
    let s:rep = [a:rep, v:count ? v:count : get(a:000, 0, 1)]
    set operatorfunc=RepWincmd
    return 'g@l'
endfunction

" optional number is the default shift amount
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>- <sid>setup('-', 3)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>+ <sid>setup('+', 3)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>< <sid>setup('<', 5)
nnoremap <expr> <c-w>> <sid>setup('>', 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You will have to remap a `.` to do series of changes that your mapping introduces.

It is not that simple to do and it might interfere with other things user might have mapped on the dot like `vim-repeat` of Tim Pope (which does exactly that and exposes API for other plugins to have complex repeats with a dot)